# Progress alert not dismissing from view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to create a function for showing and dismissing a ProgressDialog in Swift 3.  But in this code the dialog is not dismissing from the view controller.

```
func showLoadingDialog(show : Bool)  {
    if show {
        self.alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have also tried the following methods for dismiss this dialog, but none of them worked:

```
self.alert.view.removeFromSuperview()

self.alert.view.alpha = 0
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please help me. If you guys have any alternate solution, please make a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//Try this

```
func showLoadingDialog(show : Bool)  {
        if show {
            if self.alert == nil{
                self.alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
                loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
                loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
                self.alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
            }
            if !self.alert.isBeingPresented {
                 self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }else{
            self.alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In `func showLoadingDialog`,

try to use

`self.alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

instead of

`self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

Comment: it is working for one time.But I am calling this function multiple time in my ViewController. the second time the alert not dismissing. I am calling this  function from network response  block.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more code blocks on how it is implemented so that we can understand more about the issue. Thanks!